# How to put a URL into a link?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So the problem i'm having is in the Google map infoWindow. In the infoWindow I want to display a link for the directions, but i'm having trouble display the link. When displaying the linking i'm thinking of using

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=
```

and adding the encoded address to it.

Here is the JavaScript code. I used encodeURIComponenet to add to the end of the url.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+encodeURIComponent(address);
      var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address+'<br/>' + '<a href="??";>Directions</a>';      

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

I don't know how to display the url into the href because i know in PHP i would be able to echo it and it would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you simply concatenate the URL in there, like you did for name/address?  Am I missing something?  Also, I recommend avoiding `<b>` tags.  Use CSS classes and/or `<strong>`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Yeah :9, don't see how i missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to be careful with you quotes and double quotes.  This should work (if url is a valid url...)

```
var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address+'<br/>' + '<a href="'+url+'">Directions</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't just be string concatenation?

```
var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address+'<br/>' + '<a href="' + url + '";>Directions</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address+'<br/>' + 'Directions'.link(url);
```